# Find PHP process that logs to file

Tags: process, apache-httpd, logs, php

I have started a PHP script via browser and due to a loop error the script continues to be executed even after closing the browser. I am noticing it since the script is logging error messages to my logfile (path known).

We have a Apache server where many developers work together and the user is `nmdev`. So how can I find out what process it the one running and logging to my logfile?

`ps -afe | grep php53` gives me many processes of today like:

`nmdev    26518 24151  0 11:51 ?        00:00:00 /opt/xxx/yyy/apache-php5/bin/httpd -k start`

Answer (score 2):

The solution for my problem was to use:

`/sbin/fuser /path/to/logfile`

That gave me all the processes writing to the file. I killed them all without mercy. Problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lsof` to find PID of the process accessing a certain file:

```
[rhusar@rhusar ~]$ ps xafu | grep cat
COMMAND  PID   USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF     NODE NAME
cat     5700 rhusar    1w   REG   0,29       57 13154551 /tmp/abc
```

However, if its logging via HTTPd itself, I would think you might only see the PID of the HTTPd instance.

Comment: Yes I know but it is not available `-bash: lsof: command not found` and I am not root.

Comment: `lsof` command is usually a separate package you need to have installed (e.g. `lsof-4.87-2.fc19.x86_64` on current fedora). Get in touch with the admin and have it installed.